# Error response from daemon: Container xxx is not running

Tags: docker, containers

I am following the official tutorial of Docker.I typed the same code as the tutorial,but got an unexpected error as shown below.I checked the Dashboard and found the container had exited.The log is shown below,which was too complicated to understand for me.I wonder why this happens and how I can keep the container running without exiting unexpectedly.
[Screenshot of the tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyFQp.png)    [Screenshot of the CMD error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFHgl.png)    [The Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mq0Cr.png)       [Log of the container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/II57z.png)

Updated:I used `docker run -d    --network todo-app --network-alias mysql    -v todo-mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql    -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret    -e MYSQL_DATABASE=todos    mysql:5.7` to successfully create the container.However,when I typed`docker exec -it <container-id> mysql -p`,I got an unexpected error.`Error response from daemon: Container <container-id> is not running`.Above `<container-id>`s were all substituted correctly.

Comment: The last ERROR in the log tells you the problem: wrong format of private key. double check how you generated the private key and try to validate it.

Comment: You seem to have attached four links to images to your question, instead of including the source code and error message.  Can you [edit] the question to include these details directly in the question (not behind links) and in plain text (not images)?

Comment: I just followed the tutorial and I have no idea how to generate the private key.I think it's just an automatical process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your container logs, I spotted a line saying that the DB didn't shutdown correctly.

As a result the volume may have corrupted files? In your case the certificates.

Try clearing all data in the volume, destroy the container. And repeat the process from scratch

Comment: WOW!Thank you so much! I deleted the volume and repeated the process,everything just worked out! It's amazing!！ Thank you again! I really spent quite a number of time on this and got almost desperate.

Comment: @JunqingChen That's awesome. Glad to be of help. If you don't mind then please approve and upvote the answer

Comment: I'm new in stackoverflow,and I got this when upvoting the answer"Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."Hopefully it's still of help.Thanks again for your kind help!

Comment: Yeah,I have accepted the answer successfully.But I am still not capable of upvoting it as my reputation is less than 15.